# "Writes" in Google style Python docstring?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

In Google style Python docstring, one can specify `Args`, `Returns`, `Raises` as follows.

```
"""This is an example of Google style.

Args:
    param1: This is the first param.
    param2: This is a second param.

Returns:
    This is a description of what is returned.

Raises:
    KeyErr
"""
```

I have many functions that, instead of returning stuff, write the results to the disk. I find it often useful to also document what the function will write to disk, e.g., using `Writes:`, which doesn't seem supported by `sphinx.ext.napoleon`.

What is the best way of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

For versions `sphinx>=1.8.2`, you can have a [custom section](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sphinxcontrib.napoleon.html#sphinxcontrib.napoleon.Config.napoleon_custom_sections).

In your `conf.py` you should add the option `napoleon_custom_sections = ('Writes', 'Parameters')` (To create an alias with Parameters for instance)

Then you can write your docstring this way:

```
from sphinxcontrib.napoleon import Config
from sphinxcontrib.napoleon import GoogleDocstring

config = Config(napoleon_use_param=True, napoleon_use_rtype=True, napoleon_custom_sections=('Writes', 'Parameters'))
docstring="""This is an example of Google style with a custom section.

Args:
    param1: This is the first param.
    param2: This is a second parpytham.

Returns:
    This is a description of what is returned.

Raises:
    KeyErr

Writes:
    write1: This is writting things !

"""

print(GoogleDocstring(docstring, config))
```

Comment: This sounds really promising!

Comment: This is the closest I could get to write nicely the section, if that does not help you, do not hesitate, I will search a bit more ! :)

Comment: Hey this almost worked, but since `Writes` is just an alias to `Parameters`, it will just show up as "Parameters". I think this conflicts with the already existing "Parameters". Plus I wish to have the section name to be "Writes", rather than another "Parameters."

Comment: I will have a look at it tomorrow ! :)